# Paypal Adaptive Chained Payments - Sender's amount is primary receiver's amount not the total amount. How to fix?

Tags: php, paypal, payment, paypal-adaptive-payments, chained

I'm developing a service where the sender pays an amount, 95% of which goes to one receiver and 5% to the other. (e.g., $100 paid, $95 less fees to primary and $5 to secondary.) In this example, the sender is seeing $95 as his amount to pay and not $100 and I'm not understanding why.

Here is where the amounts are set in an array corresponding to another array of Paypal e-mail addresses.

```
$receiverAmountArray = array(
        .5*$backing_amount,
        .95*$backing_amount
        );
```

The second e-mail address is set to primary. The receiver of the largest amount has to be primary.

```
$receiverPrimaryArray = array(
        'false',
        'true'
        );
```

CallPay (from Paypal's library) is called:

```
$resArray = CallPay ($actionType, $cancelUrl, $returnUrl, $currencyCode, $receiverEmailArray,
                        $receiverAmountArray, $receiverPrimaryArray, $receiverInvoiceIdArray,
                        $feesPayer, $ipnNotificationUrl, $memo, $pin, $preapprovalKey,
                        $reverseAllParallelPaymentsOnError, $senderEmail, $trackingId
);
```

Here is the CallPay function. Sorry for length:

```
function CallPay( $actionType, $cancelUrl, $returnUrl, $currencyCode, $receiverEmailArray, $receiverAmountArray,
                        $receiverPrimaryArray, $receiverInvoiceIdArray, $feesPayer, $ipnNotificationUrl,
                        $memo, $pin, $preapprovalKey, $reverseAllParallelPaymentsOnError, $senderEmail, $trackingId )
    {
        /* Gather the information to make the Pay call.
            The variable nvpstr holds the name value pairs
        */

        // required fields
        $nvpstr = "actionType=" . urlencode($actionType) . "&currencyCode=" . urlencode($currencyCode);
        $nvpstr .= "&returnUrl=" . urlencode($returnUrl) . "&cancelUrl=" . urlencode($cancelUrl);

        if (0 != count($receiverAmountArray))
        {
            reset($receiverAmountArray);
            while (list($key, $value) = each($receiverAmountArray))
            {
                if ("" != $value)
                {
                    $nvpstr .= "&receiverList.receiver(" . $key . ").amount=" . urlencode($value);
                }
            }
        }

        if (0 != count($receiverEmailArray))
        {
            reset($receiverEmailArray);
            while (list($key, $value) = each($receiverEmailArray))
            {
                if ("" != $value)
                {
                    $nvpstr .= "&receiverList.receiver(" . $key . ").email=" . urlencode($value);
                }
            }
        }

        if (0 != count($receiverPrimaryArray))
        {
            reset($receiverPrimaryArray);
            while (list($key, $value) = each($receiverPrimaryArray))
            {
                if ("" != $value)
                {
                    $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&receiverList.receiver(" . $key . ").primary=" . urlencode($value);
                }
            }
        }

        if (0 != count($receiverInvoiceIdArray))
        {
            reset($receiverInvoiceIdArray);
            while (list($key, $value) = each($receiverInvoiceIdArray))
            {
                if ("" != $value)
                {
                    $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&receiverList.receiver(" . $key . ").invoiceId=" . urlencode($value);
                }
            }
        }

        // optional fields
        if ("" != $feesPayer)
        {
            $nvpstr .= "&feesPayer=" . urlencode($feesPayer);
        }

        if ("" != $ipnNotificationUrl)
        {
            $nvpstr .= "&ipnNotificationUrl=" . urlencode($ipnNotificationUrl);
        }

        if ("" != $memo)
        {
            $nvpstr .= "&memo=" . urlencode($memo);
        }

        if ("" != $pin)
        {
            $nvpstr .= "&pin=" . urlencode($pin);
        }

        if ("" != $preapprovalKey)
        {
            $nvpstr .= "&preapprovalKey=" . urlencode($preapprovalKey);
        }

        if ("" != $reverseAllParallelPaymentsOnError)
        {
            $nvpstr .= "&reverseAllParallelPaymentsOnError=" . urlencode($reverseAllParallelPaymentsOnError);
        }

        if ("" != $senderEmail)
        {
            $nvpstr .= "&senderEmail=" . urlencode($senderEmail);
        }

        if ("" != $trackingId)
        {
            $nvpstr .= "&trackingId=" . urlencode($trackingId);
        }

        /* Make the Pay call to PayPal */
        $resArray = hash_call("Pay", $nvpstr);

        /* Return the response array */
        return $resArray;
    }
```

Here's the value of $nvpstr right before the call. Is it possible that Paypal is just making the payment amount the primary payment? That doesn't make sense in the context of chained payments.

```
actionType=PAY¤cyCode=USD&returnUrl=https%3A%2F%2F.com%2Fview_profile.php&cancelUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fexamplefunding.com%2Fview_profile.php&receiverList.receiver(0).amount=95&receiverList.receiver(1).amount=5&receiverList.receiver(0).email=recip_1334204171_biz%40example.com&receiverList.receiver(1).email=example_1334201682_biz%40example.com&receiverList.receiver(0).primary=true&receiverList.receiver(1).primary=false&receiverList.receiver(0).invoiceId=5c4e2902cbe484a0db37284f0144994c&receiverList.receiver(1).invoiceId=6f3d8ce65d1a59b41f8822ba6129ea58&feesPayer=PRIMARYRECEIVER&memo=New+Draft+Lines+-+ExampleFunding.com&senderEmail=paypal_1334201496_per%40example.com&trackingId=mqN8SSgIq
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Paypal's Adaptive Payments Documentation](https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/PP_AdaptivePayments.pdf%20%2aPaypal%27s%20Adaptive%20Payments%20Documentation):

> In a chained payment, the sender pays the primary receiver an amount,
>   from which the  primary receiver pays secondary receivers. The sender
>   only knows about the primary receiver,  not the secondary receivers.

Therefore, this is working as intended. In order to pay 5% of the total amount to the secondary receiver, I must change this:

```
$receiverAmountArray = array(
        .05*$backing_amount,
        .95*$backing_amount
        );
```

to this:

```
$receiverAmountArray = array(
        .05*$backing_amount,
        $backing_amount
        );
```

It was my mistake to think that the total amount was the sum of the individual receiver amounts in the array.

Answer (score 0):

example: total_amount = 100;

if we set receiverList.receiver(0).primary=true then receiverList.receiver(0).amount = total_amount;

and receiverList.receiver(1).amount=95%*total_amount